# Pass a dictionary from Djanjo view to another view via javascript

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary

I have a view that passes a dictionary (along with a couple of forms and strings) to an HTML template. The template has a js file. I am accessing the dictionary in js like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
    var request_dict = {{request_dict|safe}};
 </script>
```

Now, I want to pass this on to another view via POST(not necessarily, it can change). The format of request.POST in second view should be like a dictionary inside a dictionary. But the dictionary(request_dict) comes as a list instead of a dictionary.

How can I resolve this? Do I have to use JSON? Please mention if my explanation is wierd.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON, its safe.

View:

```
retutn render(request, 'template.html', {
    'request_dict': json.dumps(request_dict),
}
```

Templete:

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
    var request_dict = JSON.parse('{{request_dict|safe}}');
</script>
```

Comment: request.POST that i get in my second view is like this:
{u'var1':[u'true'], u'request_dict[value1]': [u''], u'request_dict[value2]':[u'something'] }. The values are accessible, but request_dict is not in a dictionary format.